# how can i make part of a JLabel Visible under mouse movement?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouseover

how do i make a part of the JLabel, relative to the position of the mouse, visible only under the location of the mouse. the JLabel has an image of a room. i want the mouse to act as a flashlight, and only display, in a large circumference around the mouse the part of the JLabel/image that the mouse is hovering over.

Comment: With some difficulty, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488853/java-mouse-flashlight-effect/15489299#15489299) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388942/clear-portion-of-graphics-with-underlying-image/18392674#18392674)

Comment: wow this is great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JLayer`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Components With the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for various examples.

The section on `Responding to Events` has an example that does what you want.